# How to write a program that "remembers" a previously guessed number?

Tags: c++, random

I'm working on a question which is asking me to have a guessing game with the computer... with the computer being the guesser:

> "Write a program that calculates a random number *1* through *100*. The program then asks the user to guess the number.
>   If the user guesses too high or too low then the program should output *"too high"* or *"too low"* accordingly.
>   The program must let the user continue to guess until the user correctly guesses the number.
> ★ Modify the program to output how many guesses it took the user to correctly guess the right number.
> ★★ Modify the program so that instead of the user guessing a number the computer came up with, the computer guesses the number that the user has secretely decided. The user must tell the computer whether it guesed too high or too low."

**So far I've did** the first couple bits, but I'm stuck on the two-star part, where the program guesses the number.

This is my code below: (but as you'll be able to tell, it doesn't quite work as planned)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int compnumber;
string ok;

cout << "Think of a number between 1 and 100. Type 'ok' and I'll try and guess it." << endl;

cin >> ok;
cout << endl;

srand(time(NULL));

compnumber = rand() % 100 + 1;

cout << compnumber << endl;
cin >> ok;

while (ok != "correct")
{
    if (ok == "high")
    {
    compnumber = rand() % compnumber + 1;
    cout << compnumber << endl;
    cin >> ok;
    }
    if (ok == "low")
    {
    compnumber = rand() % 100 + compnumber;
    cout << compnumber << endl;
    cin >> ok;
    }

}
cout << "I won!" << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way for the program to remember the number it previously guessed. I tried using the `if (ok == "high")` and `if (ok == "low")` to create what you'd call *"boundaries"* for the program "to remember". So if it was too high, it would remember the value it just guessed was too high, and would therefore guess lower than that, and vice versa with if it was too low.

But I'm struggling to get the program to remember both parts, e.g. if my secret number was *50*, the computer guessed *80*. I'd say it was too high, so it would go lower. If it then guessed *40*, I'd say it was too low and it would go higher. But the program is then going HIGHER than it's original guess of *80*, and sometimes even higher than *100* which I don't understand!

Any help would be appreciated. I have no idea if I'm going the right way with this, so any pointers would help! Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like homework so I'll just point you in the right direction. You need an upper and lower bound, the computers guesses must be between this. The upper and lower bound start as 100 and 1 and you keep adjusting them until you get the correct value.

Comment: Hmm...how to remember something. If only computers had something like "memory"...

Comment: @IKavanagh it's actually just on cplusplus.com, just a bit of self-learning for myself! Perfect thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two variables to store the high and low guesses so that the computer knows the range in which it should guess. Add this to your code:

```
int high = 101;
int low = 0;
```

Then when the computer guesses too high do this:

```
high = compnumber;
compnumber = ( rand() % (high-low - 1) ) + low;
```

And when too low, this:

```
low = compnumber;
compnumber = ( rand() % (high-low - 1) ) + low;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You need two extra variables - say `int at_least = 1, at_most = 100;` - as you get told "high" or "low", modify those to reflect the new knowledge of the range of possible answers.  When you choose a new `compnumber`, keep it in that range by modding by the current size of the range and adding `at_least`.